# Validating specific set of form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and while submitting i need to loop through only set of specific text boxes and display an alert in a manner of " label name - text field value" , where ever the text box value is blank/null.To group the specific set of text boxes, i think i should define their ids in a specific manner ( e.g group1, group2 etc), please suggest.And is this a good idea to find the label name using text box id, Or it can be done in simpler approach. Thanks.

```
<form>
<table>
<tr id=""><td width='5%'><label> Row 1 :</label></td>other text boxes</tr>
<tr id=""><td width='5%'><label> Row 2 :</label></td><td width='10%'><input type='text' id=textbox1 name=text1></td></tr>
<tr id=""><td width='5%'><label> Row 3 :</label></td><td width='10%'><input type='text' id=textbox1 name=text1></td></tr>
<tr id=""><td width='5%'><label> Row 4 :</label></td><td width='10%'><input type='text' id=textbox1 name=text1></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you have `<tr id="">`? BTW, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: I can't see any grouping of inputs here

Comment: are you trying to group it based on name attribute

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e4bdf/1/

Comment: checkout the demo I posted above

Comment: What are you trying to select, just inputs that have no value, inputs within that particular form or table, inputs with a specific name or class ?

Comment: @Arun, Thanks. i just tried to check this 'input[name^="text"]' , in jsfiddle, but i am getting this error if i click Run : {"error": "Please use POST request"}. any work around you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/ALQtj/1/)

*HTML*

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr id="">
            <td width='5%'>
                <label>Row 1 :</label>
            </td>
            <td width='10%'>
                <input type='text' class="required" name="text1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="">
            <td width='5%'>
                <label>Row 2 :</label>
            </td>
            <td width='10%'>
                <input type='text' class="required" name="text2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="">
            <td width='5%'>
                <label>Row 3 :</label>
            </td>
            <td width='10%'>
                <input type='text' class="required" name="text3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="">
            <td width='5%'>
                <label>Row 4 :</label>
            </td>
            <td width='10%'>
                <input type='text' class="required" name="text4" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

*jQuery*

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var requireds = $(':text.required');
        requireds.each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).val() === "") {
                var label = $(this).closest('tr').find('label').text();
                alert(label + 'is empty!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.i just tried in jsfiddle, its not working.can you please check once.

Comment: It works fine for me..... put some input in two of the rows, click Submit and it reports which two rows are empty prefixed by the label.